# How to show Hijri and Gregorian calendar in android's calendarView at same time?

Tags: android-calendar, gregorian-calendar, calendarview, hijri

I want to show Hijri (Islamic Calendar) and Gregorian calendar's date on my calendarView with month name together or separately on two different calendars. I have tried many libraries from github but find nothing most of them only show simple calendarview with no date.

Comment: What did your search bring up?

Comment: We got what you want but what is your question? Have you done something and stuck somewhere?

Comment: i have used "ptrstovka.calendarview2.CalendarView2" from github but it did not show current date it just open the current month